# Servlet and support for large quentities files downloaded

Tags: java, servlets, architecture, download

I need to create a high available solution for downloading files (from a server) via a web app.

It is about downloading PDF's.

I am afraid that a simple tomcat and servlet based solution is not enough for supporting a huge load.

Medium files (up to 10 MB) and thousands of users. Let;s say not more then 2000 concurrent

Do you have a suggestion of what would be a good solution for this scenario ?

Thank you

Comment: don;t understand the - for this...BUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDFs are kept as file, you can use Apache to help to serve them as statistic content. There are a lot of how to use Apache with Tomcat and a lot of best practices about this in google.

If the PDFs are kept as dynamic content, you can use Varnish (https://www.varnish-cache.org/) to help as to handle by caching this thing.

Any cases you choose, you still can use Tomcat as the application server.

Answer (score 2):

Why is Tomcat not sufficient?

Are your files stored in the filesystem? You might be able to use any old web server- and you will surely find one which is scalable enough for nearly any purpose.

Comment: i did not say is not...i asked if there might be some better practices,tools...i do not have the capacity of simulating that amount of traffic

Comment: 2000 concurrent users does not sound *that* difficult to simulate using a regular stress testing tool. You might have to use several nodes to simulate it, but it should definitely be doable.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Tomcat 6,7` can handle this - but there are also a lot of enterprise servers like `Glassfish` and `Jboss`. Also it depends what framework are you using - if you're betting on `JSF`, you could use a component library like `Primefaces` which has some `fileDownloadController` already implemented.

Almost every java web framework has a fileDownloadController(or something similar) implemented: Spring(MVC),Struts2 etc